# Reusing a variable in an Oracle SQL query

Tags: oracle

Very simple question, but one I can't seem to find an answer to.

I have a variable calculated at the start of an Oracle SQL script (in TOAD, if that makes a difference), and I hoped to reuse it later in an UPDATE statement.

Variable is declared and then set here:

```
 DECLARE
 v_months number;  
 v_check number;
 BEGIN  
 v_check := '1'
 SELECT (total_due/monthly_amount) INTO v_months FROM TABLE1 WHERE ...
```

and will return a numeric value of, say, 20.

and I want to use that figure here:

```
IF(v_check = 1)
update TABLE2 set paid = 'YES' where sequence between v_months and 48;
```

This doesn't seem to be possible as the variable is flagged up as an invalid identifier, but is there a way round this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a complete [MRE]. If you only give us snippets then we have to guess what comes before, between and after your snippets and you are less likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: SQL script window doesn't work like a worksheet, every statement is a separate statement and knows nothing about other statements executed earlier. Please, show your entire code that throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DECLARE` the variable at the start of the PL/SQL block and then just re-use it in the same PL/SQL block and it works:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_months PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT (total_due/monthly_amount) INTO v_months FROM TABLE1;

  update TABLE2 set paid = 'YES' where sequence between v_months and 48;
END;
/
```

If you are trying to re-use it between different PL/SQL blocks then it will not work using a PL/SQL variable.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=91dafe5e43a81b967b12a46a2146bc83)*

---

If you want to use a variable in multiple statements then you can [use bind variables](https://blog.toadworld.com/using_bind_variables):

```sql
VARIABLE v_months NUMBER

BEGIN
  SELECT (total_due/monthly_amount) INTO :v_months FROM TABLE1;
END;
/

update TABLE2 set paid = 'YES' where sequence between :v_months and 48;
```

Comment: thanks - that explains what was wrong - I thought the variable could be carried across differing  blocks of code.